# Load Javascript and CSS files depending on the page in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

I am creating a web-based application in PHP. I have separated headers and footers and have created separate files for them "headers.php" && "footers.php". The "headers.php" file has all the styles in it and also the CSS files of different libraries and the same goes with the "footers.php" file, it has all the scripts in it.

My question is, is there a way where I can include all these different CSS and scripts depending upon the template.

here is an example:

```
if(template == 'somefilename.php'){
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/libraries/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: With PHP almost every thing is possible, but I think you need to explain more (with maybe examples) on how your `template` works

Comment: The way you have outlined is a way to do it - what is the issue with the way you have proposed?

Comment: @Baracuda078 I have updated my question hope you will understand now. Thanks

Comment: @Luke I want to see if it is the best way to do it?

Comment: `I want to see if it is the best way to do it?` which would attract opinions and be off topic here - there is no "best way" only suggested based on what people do and prefer. What you are suggesting works, so do switch statements, so does a preload class system, it's what works for you and what you are doing

Comment: The templates themselves could "register" their interest in certain header and footer things before they render. WordPress, for instance, has a concept of enqueueing scripts and styles, and allows for minor dependency management.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct, you could do the following:

In the file, lets say `home.php` in that file you include or require your header.php and footer.php

```
// home.php
<?php
$addToHeader = '<script type="text/javascript" src="js/libraries/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>';

require 'header.php';

// your html content

require footer.php;
?>

// header.php

// Your header code with your links etc...
<?php
if (isset($addToHeader)) {// Check if $addToHeader exist to prevent undefined errors
  echo $addToHeader;
}
```

By doing something like this you can inject different links/scripts into your pages. The same can be done within your footer but then with an other variable name.